# Android Maven compilation failure

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I've been struggling with this for hours now... I have a maven Android lib project, and compiling it fails with the following debug output:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.4:compile from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.4, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@77cde100]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.4:compile' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera
[DEBUG]   (f) buildDirectory = D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\classes, C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-module-manager\0.0.1\nu-art-module-manager-0.0.1.jar, C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-exception-handling\0.0.1\nu-art-exception-handling-0.0.1.jar, C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-reflection\0.0.1\nu-art-reflection-0.0.1.jar, C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-core\0.0.1\nu-art-core-0.0.1.jar, C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-tools\0.0.1\nu-art-tools-0.0.1.jar, C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\org\jdom\jdom\1.1\jdom-1.1.jar, C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\rexml\0.0.1\rexml-0.0.1.jar, C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\cyborg\0.0.1\cyborg-0.0.1.jar, C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\android\framework\android-intermediate-package\0.0.1\android-intermediate-package-0.0.1.jar, C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\google\android\android\3.2_r1\android-3.2_r1.jar]
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java, D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\generated-sources\extracted-dependencies\src\main\java, D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\generated-sources\r, D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\generated-sources\aidl]
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerId = javac
[DEBUG]   (f) debug = true
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) fork = false
[DEBUG]   (f) generatedSourcesDirectory = D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\generated-sources\annotations
[DEBUG]   (f) optimize = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) outputFileName = cyborg-module-camera-0.0.1
[DEBUG]   (f) projectArtifact = com.nu.art.software.cyborg:cyborg-module-camera:apklib:0.0.1
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@201d592a
[DEBUG]   (f) showDeprecation = false
[DEBUG]   (f) showWarnings = false
[DEBUG]   (f) source = 1.6
[DEBUG]   (f) staleMillis = 0
[DEBUG]   (f) target = 1.6
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using compiler 'javac'.
[DEBUG] Source directories: [D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java
 D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\generated-sources\r
 D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\generated-sources\aidl]
[DEBUG] Classpath: [D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\classes
 C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-module-manager\0.0.1\nu-art-module-manager-0.0.1.jar
 C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-exception-handling\0.0.1\nu-art-exception-handling-0.0.1.jar
 C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-reflection\0.0.1\nu-art-reflection-0.0.1.jar
 C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-core\0.0.1\nu-art-core-0.0.1.jar
 C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-tools\0.0.1\nu-art-tools-0.0.1.jar
 C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\org\jdom\jdom\1.1\jdom-1.1.jar
 C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\rexml\0.0.1\rexml-0.0.1.jar
 C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\cyborg\0.0.1\cyborg-0.0.1.jar
 C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\android\framework\android-intermediate-package\0.0.1\android-intermediate-package-0.0.1.jar
 C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\google\android\android\3.2_r1\android-3.2_r1.jar]
[DEBUG] Output directory: D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\classes
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG]  D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\classes
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-module-manager\0.0.1\nu-art-module-manager-0.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-exception-handling\0.0.1\nu-art-exception-handling-0.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-reflection\0.0.1\nu-art-reflection-0.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-core\0.0.1\nu-art-core-0.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-tools\0.0.1\nu-art-tools-0.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\org\jdom\jdom\1.1\jdom-1.1.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\rexml\0.0.1\rexml-0.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\cyborg\0.0.1\cyborg-0.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\android\framework\android-intermediate-package\0.0.1\android-intermediate-package-0.0.1.jar
[DEBUG]  C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\google\android\android\3.2_r1\android-3.2_r1.jar
[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java
[DEBUG]  D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\generated-sources\extracted-dependencies\src\main\java
[DEBUG]  D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\generated-sources\r
[DEBUG]  D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\generated-sources\aidl
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\classes -classpath D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\classes;C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-module-manager\0.0.1\nu-art-module-manager-0.0.1.jar;C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-exception-handling\0.0.1\nu-art-exception-handling-0.0.1.jar;C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-reflection\0.0.1\nu-art-reflection-0.0.1.jar;C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-core\0.0.1\nu-art-core-0.0.1.jar;C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\nu-art-tools\0.0.1\nu-art-tools-0.0.1.jar;C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\org\jdom\jdom\1.1\jdom-1.1.jar;C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\rexml\0.0.1\rexml-0.0.1.jar;C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\cyborg\0.0.1\cyborg-0.0.1.jar;C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\android\framework\android-intermediate-package\0.0.1\android-intermediate-package-0.0.1.jar;C:\Users\TacB0sS\.m2\repository\com\google\android\android\3.2_r1\android-3.2_r1.jar; -sourcepath D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java;D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\generated-sources\r;D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\generated-sources\aidl; D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\modules\camera\core\CameraLayer.java D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\modules\camera\core\CameraModule.java D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\modules\camera\core\CameraException.java -s D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\generated-sources\annotations -g -nowarn -target 1.6 -source 1.6 -encoding UTF-8
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\modules\camera\core\CameraLayer.java:[79,80] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getRotation()
location: class android.view.Display
[ERROR] D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\modules\camera\core\CameraModule.java:[50,23] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getNumberOfCameras()
location: class android.hardware.Camera
[ERROR] D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\modules\camera\core\CameraModule.java:[66,26] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CameraInfo
location: class android.hardware.Camera
[ERROR] D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\modules\camera\core\CameraModule.java:[66,78] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CameraInfo
location: class android.hardware.Camera
[ERROR] D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\modules\camera\core\CameraModule.java:[88,19] open() in android.hardware.Camera cannot be applied to (int)
[ERROR] D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\modules\camera\core\CameraModule.java:[109,26] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CameraInfo
location: class android.hardware.Camera
[ERROR] D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\modules\camera\core\CameraModule.java:[109,78] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class CameraInfo
location: class android.hardware.Camera
[ERROR] D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\modules\camera\core\CameraModule.java:[124,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setDisplayOrientation(int)
location: class android.hardware.Camera
[INFO] 8 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

NOTE that one of the classpath variables is:
C:\Users\TacB0sS.m2\repository\com\google\android\android\3.2_r1\android-3.2_r1.jar

I've doubled and triple checked this, and I'm sure that these method and classes are in the above jar, in Eclipse I use the same jar in the standard build path, and it compiles just fine, also browsing it shows the object and method included.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

Some of the effective pom:

```
<properties>
    <owner>Adam Zehavi</owner>
    <android.version>3.2_r1</android.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <android.sdk>13</android.sdk>
    <company.name>Nu-Art Software</company.name>
    <nickname>TacB0sS</nickname>
    <android.emulator.name>emulator1</android.emulator.name>
</properties>
...
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nu.art.software.cyborg</groupId>
        <artifactId>cyborg</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nu.art.software.cyborg</groupId>
        <artifactId>cyborg</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>3.2_r1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
...
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please, provide your POM

Comment: The pom structure is complex but I'll post some of the effective pom..

Comment: Is it your library project's pom.xml or main project's pom.xml? Please attach complete pom.xml if possible.

Comment: What is your configuration of the android maven plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is with wrong sdk level in android-maven-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>                    
                <sdk>
                    <platform>13</platform> <!-- or ${android.sdk} in your case -->
                </sdk>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: That got me to the right answer... I had an old profile I should have deleted somewhere in the pom hierarchy, which had an empty configuration for the android plugin, resulting in the error.

Answer (score 0):

First the error messages indicate that your dependencies are not ok cause you are missing a needed class (library)..

```
[ERROR] D:\Development\Java\Projects\Frameworks\Cyborg\Cyborg Module - Camera\src\main\java\com\nu\art\software\cyborg\modules\camera\core\CameraLayer.java:[79,80] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getRotation()
location: class android.view.Display
```

The question is where do you get the jar (C:\Users\TacB0sS.m2\repository\com\google\android\android\3.2_r1\android-3.2_r1.jar) you are using. If i simply search via google after it  found a jar but this jar does not contain the given classes.... Furthermore there seemed to be some hints about [problems(see issues).](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer)

Furthermore i would recooment not to define things in Maven which are already covered by the conventions

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The above can be simplified to (take care using an up-to-date-version of the maven-compiler-plugin current: 2.5.1).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```